# Where does the data transformation logic occur in a traditional (non-mediator) MVC architecture?

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller

I am currently learning the MVC style of architecture, using Java (Swing, in particular).

I understand that the view is the graphical interface that the end-user uses.

I understand that the model represents the information in working memory, the database and the link between the two.

I understand that the controller is supposed to handle which view is in use, and what happens when the user generates an event.

However, I am confused as to where the raw data, taken from the view, is transformed into a usable data structure for the program's working memory? By the controller? Or by the model?

Let's say we have a Swing program that displays the different fields from a ArrayList of type Person in a table. The Person data type will hold different fields relating to a person's personal information, such as name, age, address, etc.

Let's also say we have a form in our program which we use to submit information. When we enter information into the form, we can then click a "Submit" button, which then takes the raw field data and places it into our data structure, our ArrayList of type Person in our Model.

The thing here though is that the raw field data (several different Strings) needs to be converted into an object of Person type (which holds several different String fields,) in order to add it to the ArrayList of type Person.

My confusion here is where is the data transformation logic supposed to occur here?

Is the Controller supposed to know about the Person data type, and is it supposed to convert the data into type Person(by a Listener handling the "submission" event), and then pass that object to the Model?

Or is it the Controller's job merely to -ferry- this raw data towards the Model package, and the Model should have an internal mechanism for converting the raw field data into a Person object?

In this sort of situation, where exactly do the responsibilities of each component (the Controller and Model) start and stop?

Comment: One of the model classes would contain the code to create a Person.  One of the controller classes would execute this code so that it can tell the View about any errors when creating a Person.  Generally, when there's a confusion as to where code belongs in the MVC pattern, it's because two parts share the responsibility for making something happen.  Also, you can have two models, one for the GUI and one for the database.  The business logic consists of the two models communicating with each other.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc is correct; for example, a `JTable` is a view of a `TableModel` holding a `List<Person>`, but the table might also act as a controller when it evokes a `TableCellEditor`  or opens a `JDialog` to edit a single `Person`.